# node js receive JSON from xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I implemented a post method based on xmlhttprequest:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log('Request finished. Do processing here')
    }
  }
  console.log(sensorData)
  xhttp.open('POST', postUrl, true)
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(    [
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:55:03.000Z',
    channel: 'Ch2', },
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:56:03.000Z',
    channel: 'Ch2'},
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:57:03.000Z',
    channel: 'Ch2'}
]))
```

but when the server receives the post request, it can not print data correctly:

```
app.post('/post', callbackPost)
function callbackPost (req, res) {
  try {
        var body = JSON.stringify(req.body)
        console.log('req body: ' + body)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('post error: ' + e)
    res.send('post error')
  }
}
```

The code outputs `req body: {}`, not an array, and if I replace the code with     `console.log('req body: ' + req)`, it shows: `req body: [object Object]`

Here's my server set up:

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var app = express()
    app.listen(port)
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 100000,
      limit: '50mb',
      extended: true}))
```

Comment: res object seems like a result

Comment: Are you sure you're *not* receiving it correctly? You have an object.

Comment: Hi I just updated my code @DaveNewton

Comment: Your problem is server-side, please include more information about how your node server is configured including any relevant middleware such as a bodyparser.

Comment: @KevinB hi I updated my question

Comment: You haven't included middleware capable of parsing json strings.

Comment: @KevinB I use bodyParser, do I need to include anything else?

Comment: yeah, the same bodyparser, but setup for json

Comment: @KevinB wow it works, please add an answer, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) points out in the comment, the problem is actually cased by the middleware bodyParser. I solved the problem by replace:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 100000,
limit: '50mb',
extended: true}))
```

to

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run something like

```
console.log('req body: ' + req.body + req.body.length);
```

req.body has to be forced into a string representation, which is "[object Object]". You should try

```
console.log('req body: ', req.body);
```

This would output both variables separately.

Alternatively, you could try

```
console.log('req body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

---

I would send the data from the client as JSON, rather than an array. Perhaps like this

```
var data = [
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:55:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'},
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:56:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'},
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:57:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'}
];

xhttp.send({ data: data });
```

Then you should have access to req.body.data in your route.

Make sure you have a parser, such as bodyParser to handle the request data:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // you might want this parser too
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.data)
});

const HTTP_PORT = 9080;

app.listen(HTTP_PORT);
console.log(`Server running on port ${HTTP_PORT}`);
```

---

I see you've called your data `sensorData`. In that case the JSON would be { data: sensorData }.

I've tested the code now. Apparently you *do* have to stringify the JSON before using it with xhttp.send().

Here's my working code:

client.html:

```
<script>
const sensorData = [
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:55:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'},
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:56:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'},
  { _id: '2016-11-04T21:57:03.000Z', channel: 'Ch2'}
];

const postUrl = 'http://localhost:10080/post';

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log('Request finished. Do processing here');
  }
}
console.log(sensorData)
xhttp.open('POST', postUrl, true)
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ data: sensorData }));
</script>
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.data)
    res.send({ success: true });
});

const HTTP_PORT = 10080;

app.listen(HTTP_PORT);
console.log(`Server running on port ${HTTP_PORT}`);
```

If you're using this code verbatim, make sure you make any appropriate changes to the url and the port, as necessary.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. One more question, after I modified my code, it now prints out req body: { }. why is the xmlhttprequest not sending an array?

Comment: what.... nothing in your explanation makes sense. *"When you run something like"* clearly that was just a failed attempt, if you look at the other test you can clearly see that request body is empty. *"I would send the data from the client as JSON, rather than an array. Perhaps like this"* that is the opposite of sending it from the client as json and will result in an error.. The OP is already sending it as JSON properly.

Comment: Hi I tried to use send {data: data}, but it shows `_http_outgoing.js:458
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
`

Comment: Thanks for the kind and helpful comment @KevinB. At the time I wrote my comment, we did not know the variable was empty. The first error was in the server's console.log(). Now we know there's also a problem with the client sending the data. (I'm used to using JQuery ajax calls and I didn't notice any problems at first.) I've updated my answer with working code.